# Unable to use cy.server() with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: testing, cucumber, cypress

When I try to run cy.server() in order to mock http requests that are executed as part of the tests, I get the following error:

`Uncaught CypressError: Cannot call "cy.server()" outside a running test.....`

I don't know how to get this to work. This is my code:

```
import { Given, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.server()

  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    response: []
  })
})

const url = 'http://localhost:8080'

Given('I click the big button', () => {
  cy.visit(url)
  cy.get('.btn').click()
})

Then('I can get the MOTD', (title) => {
  cy.title().should('include', title)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the 'it()' context for Cypress. Try this:

```js
import { Given, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server()

    cy.route({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/',
      response: []
    })
  })

  it('description of the it', function () {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080'

    Given('I click the big button', () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      cy.get('.btn').click()
    })

    Then('I can get the MOTD', (title) => {
      cy.title().should('include', title)
    })
  })
```

Comment: you mixed mocha with cucumber.thats not right way to use cucumber.